# How to store a list of dates in a multi-value field using SSJS?

Tags: xpages

In the past, I've added multi-value text data to a field putting the values into a simple JavaScript array.  For example: 
doc.replaceItemValue('AlwaysAccess', ["John Doe","Bob Smith"]);

Any recommendations on how to store a series of DATES in a multi-value, Time/Date field in a Notes document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: The concept should be almost identical to a multi-value Field of *String*s, your Date(/Time) values need to be valid *NotesDateTime* values properly stored.

---

A Notes field can have multiple Date/Time values; you can see this in the Form, selecting a field of type *Date/Time* and checking "Allow multiple values".

[image: multi-value date fields]

You can also see that a multi-value of from the [*replaceItemValue* page of the Domino Designer Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_domino_Document_replaceItemValue.html).

To accomplish the same with the *NotesDominoAPI* (in SSJS), we'll need to:

1. get a handle on the [NotesItem](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_domino_Item.html) (the field, which I'll create)
2. create our values to put in the field (I'll create a couple using [*session.createDateTime*](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_domino_Session_createDateTime.html))
3. add these values to a [*java.util.Vector*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html), which will be interpreted as multi-value (you should also be able to use the SSJS *Array*, if you prefer)
4. [set the values](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_domino_Item_Values.html?cp=SSVRGU_9.0.1) to the field

Sample code (I just ran it in the *onClick* event of an *xp:button*):

```js
//create a new doc
var tmpDoc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
//give it a Form
tmpDoc.replaceItemValue("Form","MultiDateFieldForm");

//create a NotesItem
var itm:NotesItem = tmpDoc.replaceItemValue("DateFieldName",new java.util.Vector());

//create the Vector, our multi-value container
var vec:java.util.Vector = new java.util.Vector();

//create a couple NotesDateTime values to store
var first = session.createDateTime(new Date());
vec.add(first);
var second = session.createDateTime("Tomorrow");
vec.add(second);

//save the values to the item
itm.setValues(vec);

//save
tmpDoc.save();

//recycle!
first.recycle();
second.recylce();
itm.recycle();
tmpDoc.recylce();
```

[Edit]
As Frantisek Kossuth points out in the comments, be sure to recycle your NotesDomino API objects (especially the Date/Time ones). I've updated the code to reflect this.
[/Edit]

Checking a Form-based View after running, I'm giving this (field properties reflect the multi-value field of Date/Time values; two shots as it ran out of the box).

[image: first shot of the new doc, with multi-value DateTime field]
[image: second shot, shows the second value as a separate value in the "Time/Date List or Range"]

Comment: Eric, Thanks for the very detailed reply.  Much appreciated.  While you were writing that, I had been coming to pretty much the same conclusion.

Comment: Don't forget to recycle when used in iteration. DateTime object is one of the most toxic.

Comment: @Frantisek - To create the list of dates/vector I'm using a NotesDateTime object .adjustDay(1) method in a for loop.   Using `v.add( nDate )`, the vector has only references to the NotesDateTime object and the unintended result is a list containing all the same values.  The work-around that I found is to create new objects in the loop using:       `v.add(session.createDateTime(nDate.getDateOnly()));`  But this creates anonymous objects (without a way to recycle).    Any recommendations for a better way?

Comment: @DonMottolo It depends on your use case - what is the amount of the DT objects or if that snippet of code iterates through many documents or not. Eric's update does it right. NEVER use anonymous objects of NotesBase class.

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth -  Of course, you're right.  The trouble is that the number of dates is variable.  If I use the nDate.getDateOnly() the elements in the vector are text values and not date values when saved to the multi-value field.

Comment: @Eric - Any ideas on how to create a dynamic number of NotesDateTime objects?  The use case is a user specifies a start date and the number of days to repeat.  How to create object names dynamically (ex. date_1, date_2, for x number of days) to get stored in a vector within a for loop?  (that can later be recycled)

Comment: @DonMottolo Sonds like a good idea for potentially a separate question (due to level of specificity). Nathan T. Freeman talks a bit about this exact situation in [an excellent blog post](https://nathantfreeman.wordpress.com/2013/07/03/a-funny-thing-happened-on-the-way-to-the-openntf-webinar/) on the subject. I recommend you scroll down to the 5th paragraph after the first block of code. The whole article is interesting and on-topic though. Basically, this is a giant lead-in to one of the best aspects of the OpenNTF Domino API, which automates a large part of this.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, I found that I needed to create a vector to store the list of dates, and populate it with NotesDateTime objects.

```
var vRepeatDates:java.util.Vector = new java.util.Vector();
```

In my case, I needed to increment the dates x amount of times.  So, I used a for loop to add the NotesDateTime elements to the vector (while using .adjustDay(1) to increment the dates)

And finally store the vector in a field using replaceItemValue()

```
doc.replaceItemValue("RepeatInstanceDates",vRepeatDates);
```